# (Unit)test pdf generation

Tags: magento, pdf, testing, automated-tests

We implemented a magento module https://github.com/firegento/firegento-pdf/ and I plan to write tests for the module.

The problem is: The extension generates pdfs.

Is there any framework, or whatever to test pdfs? It would be totally fine if I can check for text in the pdf. I don't want to check the correct placement.

Andy ideas?

This looks promising but feels oversized. http://webcheatsheet.com/php/reading_clean_text_from_pdf.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use PdfBox for a similar module, a Java based command line utility that extracts text from a PDF and optionally converts it to HTML: http://pdfbox.apache.org/commandline/#extractText

To use it within PHPUnit tests, I wrote a PHP interface for the relevant PdfBox methods: https://github.com/schmengler/PdfBox

### Example

```
use SGH\PdfBox;

//$pdf = GENERATED_PDF;
$converter = new PdfBox;
$converter->setPathToPdfBox('/usr/bin/pdfbox-app-1.7.0.jar');
$text = $converter->textFromPdfStream($pdf);
```

Further reading: [Unit Test Generated PDFs with PHPUnit and PDFBox](http://www.schmengler-se.de/en/2014/03/unit-testen-von-generierten-pdfs-mit-phpunit-und-pdfbox/)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could use Inkscape to convert it into SVG and make asserts on some SVG Nodes.
That would do if you only want to check the text or some simple formatting.

```
$ inkscape -f invoice.pdf --export-plain-svg=thepdf.svg
```

For the correct position you need to be a bit fuzzy, though.

Nevertheless the PDF source can be plain enough to be checked with simple `strpos()`.

Answer (score 2):

You have to resign yourself to testing "we sent the right commands to Magento". Testing the output PDF would cause fragility.

Mock the PDF-writing library, and test that your code called the library correctly. This has the added benefit of speed, but requires a little more discipline. If a PDF output fails a manual inspection, you MUST fix that test-first, to keep your mocks honest.