# Software testing a pdf is created correctly

Tags: php, laravel, testing

I have written a REST application in laravel. It accepts a Json payload and creates a formatted pdf using this data.

Is it possible to write a test that checks the pdf has been generated correctly?

Edit:

Ideally I'd like to know the pdf is not corrupted, ie. Will open in a pdf reader.

Also it would be good to somehow check the content of the pdf. For example... does it contain the customers name?

Thanks.

Comment: can you define "correctly" in code?

Comment: are you expecting a yes or no reply? bcoz thats maximum what anybody can provide you with your question posted

Comment: Validating a PDF is quite complex, so there's no easy way. Since you are generating the document yourself, why do you think it's going to be invalid? A simple test would be to check the file size and perhaps the first few bytes (it should start with "%PDF").

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19714879/unittest-pdf-generation

Comment: There you go, another perfectly valid question, closed for no valid reason.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes this is possible, given that the same JSON input always generates the same PDF.

You wouldn't really check the PDF file. PDF is a complex format, based on PostScript and some dark magic.

What you can do is generate a “sample” PDF once, then write a unit test that uses the same input data to generate a PDF file, then compare this to your sample.

This would look something like (just some example code):

```
$myPdf = $pdfGenerator->generatePdf();
$samplePdf = file_get_contents('/some/example/file.pdf');

// with PHPunit
$this->assertEquals(0, strcmp($myPdf, $samplePdf));
```

That's a bit dirty, but it does the job … if something in your PDF or JSON implementation changes, the unit test will make you aware of it.

It is important, however, that your PDF generator does not insert any “dynamic” data, such as date stamps. In that case, the PDF files could obviously never be identical.

Comment: I have tried this with MPDF and with WeasyPrint - neither work.  I'm guessing some timestamp is included in the generated PDF.

Comment: I also tried <meta name="dcterms.created" content="none"> but this didn't help.