# Laravel: Is it possible to test dompdf with PHPUnit?

Tags: laravel, pdf, phpunit

I've been creating a web app with Laravel, and this app generates PDF files with `dompdf`.

I'm searching the internet for any hint as to how to test PDF files generated with `dompdf` with PHPUnit.

Here is the route for generating a PDF.

```
$this->get("/confirmation/$order->id/pdf");
```

As you can imagine, this route will generate a PDF, based on the provided ID of an `order` object. I'd like to test if the PDF contains texts as expected.

```
$this->get("/confirmation/$order->id/pdf");

$res->assertStatus(200);
//This passes

$res->assertSee("customer@mail.com");
//This email address is expected to be on the PDF, but this test fails
```

Here is the result of this test.

[image]

It seems that PHPUnit sees PDF generated by dompdf as a big binary string, so I don't know if it's possible to test PDF generated by it.

Any advice will be appreciated. (I'd consider switching to another PDF generating library, if it's testable.)

Comment: Yes, as far as PHP is concerned, it's just binary data. phpunit has no understanding of the PDF format. Your best bet is probably to generate the PDF and compare in the test to that pre-generated version to make sure they're the same. See https://gordonlesti.com/phpunit-compare-generated-pdf-files-with-imagick/ for an example.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Software testing a pdf is created correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32489513/software-testing-a-pdf-is-created-correctly)

Answer (score 0):

You can test if appropriate headers are set:

```html
$this->assertEquals('text/html; charset=UTF-8', $response->headers->get('content-type'));
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).