# Testing PDF files Codeception

Tags: php, testing, yii2, codeception

Im using **YII2**, and Im starting to build tests using **CODECEPTION**. I tried looking for answers to this question online, but I could not find any.

What is the best way to test a generated PDF file for content. The scneario that I have is that we have generated reports that are sent by mail. Those mails will have attached PDF files that I want to test. I want to use functions such as

> `$I->see($text)`

but for the generated PDF file.

How can this be done?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [(Unit)test pdf generation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19714879/unittest-pdf-generation)

Answer (score 0):

initially you must install Filesystem you can see how here [FILESYSTEM][1].
after that Make sure the browser saves the download to expected destination.
convert PDF to text file with a command line utility ($I->runShellCommand) (you have to install [CLI][2]).
make assertions on this pdf extract ($I->seeInThisFile)

```
  [1]: https://codeception.com/docs/modules/Filesystem#Installation
  [2]: https://codeception.com/docs/modules/Cli#Installation
```